# 100% height not working as expected

Tags: html, css

In my html, there're a couple of divs. but none of these is showing the background image. and, of course that's because 100% property is not working. why is this happening?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section" id="home">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="about">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="team">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="work">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="blog">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="contact">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.section {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home {
    background-image: url(img1.jpg);
}

#about {
    background-image: url(img2.jpg);
}

#team {
    background-image: url(img1.jpg);
}

#work {
    background-image: url(img2.jpg);
}

#blog {
    background-image: url(img1.jpg);
}

#contact {
    background-image: url(img2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: min-width? i never set it.

Comment: well just specifying width: 100% would work. If you have an empty div, and you do not specify any width and height it will have width and height = 0

Answer (score 3):

`100%` of what?

You need to define the parent's dimensions in order for this to work, otherwise `100%` of `0`, is also `0%`.

In this example, since the parent element is `body`, you would have to set both the height of that and `html` to `100%`. Doing this, will allow for the child element to have a height of `100%`.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7Hty/) - it works.

Comment: what's the difference between body and html in css?

Comment: weren't we talking about width?

Comment: @user2950255 Well, simply setting the parent `body` to 100% doesn't work, for the exact same reason - because it is also 0%. `html` is the parent of `body`, therefore you need to set that - as it will allow for the document to have a height of `100%`.

Comment: @sissy I thought so too at first, however, a `width` isn't required in this instance.

Comment: @JoshC i checked your fiddle and at first i was a bit astonished, but then i got an explaination and i gotta tell you that i've never considered this behavior of blocks. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your div.section needs to be relative to another div in order for the height: 100% to work.

Comment: so would assigning these divs inside a div with height 100% work?

Comment: No, your parent div needs to have a fixed height for it to work. You could also assign: height: 100% to your body, html (cf: JoshC). You may also need to add a width; following the same rules as the height.