# Stretch a div to fill up remaining space?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, html

How do I stretch a div to fill up the remaining space of a page?

I tried using this but it did not work.

```
    #home, #menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the code inside my body.

Pastebin Link : http://pastebin.com/WzRVsUG2

```
 <div data-role="page"  id="home"  >
        <div data-role="header" class ="bgimg" >
            <h1></h1>

        </div>

        <div id="menu" data-role="content" data-dom-cache="true" data-theme="c" class ="bgimg1">   
        <div><h2>Order delicious food now!</h2></div>

                 <a id= "Pizza" href = "#indexPizza" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
                        data-transition="flow" onclick= "">Pizza</a>    

                 <a id="FastFood" href = "#indexFastfood" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
                        data-transition="flow" onclick="" >Fast Food</a>

                 <a id="IndianFood" href = "#indexIndianfood" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
                        data-transition="flow" onclick="" >Indian Food</a>

                 <a id="KoreanFood" href = "#indexKoreanfood" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
                        data-transition="flow" onclick="" >Korean Food</a>

                 <a id="Restaurant" href = "#indexRestaurantfood" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" 
                        data-transition="flow" onclick= "" >Restaurant</a>      


        </div>

    </div>
```

[image]

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Just answered a question like this.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755392/100-height-not-working-as-expected/19755447#19755447 Basically, you have to define the parents height. 100% of 0 is also 0..

Comment: Hi there. In this case, the parent is #home right? I did define the height for parent. See my code above.

Comment: Set `body, html { height:100%; }` and it will work..

Comment: I did this.     #home, #menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
} But it did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Yea - but did you set `body, html { height:100%; }` ..?

Comment: I did as well. Still not working. This is my code for style. http://pastebin.com/cyXvwWRU

Comment: your CSS is broken in that pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your CSS.

```
body, html { height:100%; }

.ui-header .ui-title {
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}/* < missing brace */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#home, #menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* }     < extra brace  */
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realised that it's the missing brace that is causing this issue. It's solved now. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Get correct maximum content height

In case page header and footer has a constant height content div can be easily set to cover full available space with a little css trick:

```css
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

And here's a working example with **`Google maps api3`** demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7kGdE/

This method can be used to get correct maximum content height, and it must be used with a **pageshow** event.

```
function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    } 
    return content_height;
}
```

And here's a live jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nVs9J/

There's one thing to remember. This function will correctly get you maximum available content height and at the same time it can be used to stretch that same content. Unfortunately it cant be used to stretch img to full content height, img tag has an overhead of 3px.