# 100% height for 'display: table'

Tags: html, css

I was doing the table method for vertical aligning the content. For some reason, in the condition I am going to link, it does not work. Here is the cssdeck link:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ebke0fpw

As you can see, the height of the structure is completely dependent on the embedded Google font. I've tried making the `.meta` a `table`, and making the `.metacon` a `table-cell` to center things. However; then the `height: 100%` is not working any more.

I'm not sure about what's breaking the situation. Maybe you have the idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% height not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755392/100-height-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:**

Give `.title` a `height` and you should be fine.

E.g. just add this line to the styling of `.title`

`height: 150px;`

**Explanation**

You are telling `.meta` to have a `height` of `100%`.

Percentage based dimensions are based on the dimensions of the element's parent.

`.meta`'s parent is `.title`, which has no height declared.

Comment: But it's content will be dynamic; also when I turn the 'table' to a 'block', everything works perfectly with 100% height in the same conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The new code could be like this http://cssdeck.com/labs/lxymkq7t

use `display:table-cell` for inner elements and `display:table` for the holder. And use `vertical-align: middle`; to make aligned middle.

Comment: Check this example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ebke0fpw --- I don't want to center all the content in the title element vertically, I only want to vertically center the content in the meta element.